# Erasing element from std::unordered_map by reference to element from std::list

Tags: c++, list, iterator, unordered-map, erase

I'm implementing my LRUCache and I have an issue with understanding the removal from `std::unordered_map`. All the examples in The Internet show that it's possible to remove an element from `std::unordered_map` using reference to element from `std::list` (by using `std::list::back()`). Why is that so? I checked out the documentation for `std::unordered_map::erase()` and it accepts map iterator or key as an argument, but defenitely not a reference to an element in another data structure? Is there some specific converstion or somethign about iterators I don't understand? Thank you in advance!

P.S. I would appriciate any comments on my code structure and implementation.

Here's my code for cache:

```cpp
#ifndef LRUCACHE_H
#define LURCACHE_H

#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename KeyT = T>
class LRUCache
{

using ListItr = typename std::list<T>::iterator;

public:
    LRUCache(int size) : m_size(size)
    {

    }

    int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    bool isFull() const
    {
        return m_size == m_cache.size();
    }

    bool contains(const KeyT& key)
    {
        m_lookup_table.find(key) != m_lookup_table.end();
    }

    T get(const KeyT& key)
    {
        auto hit = m_lookup_table.find(key);
        assert("No such element present" && hit != m_lookup_table.end());
        if (hit != m_lookup_table.begin()) {
            m_cache.splice(m_cache.begin(), m_cache, hit->second);
        }
        return *(hit->second);
    }

    void set(const KeyT& key, const T& value)
    {
        auto hit = m_lookup_table.find(key);
        if (hit == m_lookup_table.end()) {
            if (isFull()) {
                m_lookup_table.erase(m_cache.back()); // <-- I don't understand this
                m_cache.pop_back();
            }
            m_cache.push_front(value);
            m_lookup_table[key] = m_cache.begin();
            return;
        }

        if (hit->second != m_cache.begin()) {
            m_cache.splice(m_cache.begin(), m_cache, hit->second);
        }
    }

    void display() const
    {
        for (const auto& e : m_cache) {
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int m_size;
    std::list<T> m_cache;
    std::unordered_map<KeyT, ListItr> m_lookup_table;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why have both `T` and `KeyT`? Please show an example of how you instantiate a `LRUCache`

Comment: Make `m_cache` a `std::list<std::pair<KeyT,T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of `erase` that accepts `Key` (which in your case equals `KeyT`), not the iterator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase.

Note that `back` from `std::list` doesn't return an iterator, but the element (in your case `T`): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back

So my guess is that the code only compiles for your default case when `KeyT = T`.

Comment: Yeah, and that's my question. I can erase from map using `Key`, but `m_cache` doesnt't contain keys, it contains elements the keys from map point to (via iterators).

Comment: *m_cache doesnt't contain keys, it contains elements the keys from map point to (via iterators)* I'm not even sure what that means, but judging from your phrasing you are not really clear about the different concepts here. `Key` is just a type, any type. In your code the `Key` in your map and the values in your list is the same type. And as already stated in the answer, none of the two methods involves iterators.

Comment: @CuriousPanCake Well, but that's what you are doing:
`m_lookup_table.erase(m_cache.back())` <- you are giving a value from `m_cache` as a key.